# How to define last-child when printing from a loop?

Tags: php, css

I use a PHP for-loop to print some portfolio items which echoes this:

```
echo "
         <a href=\"portfoliodetail.php?id=$id\" class=\"noHover\" title=\"$title\">
         <img src=\"images/portfolio/thumbnails/$bgthumbnail\" alt=\"$title\" />
        </a>
";
```

However, I'm echoing images three times, and I want the last image to have a different margin than the others.

So I thought I'd just define a :last-child in the CSS, but when I put this margin at 0, all my margins are set at 0. Maybe when echoing this in a loop it thinks all the items are the :last-child or something? Is there a way to make the margin of the last image different?

Comment: make attention: `a :last-child` != `a:last-child`.

Comment: Loop n-1 times, then echo the last one. If you're worried about code reuse extract it to a function.

Comment: This is a CSS problem, so show your (relevant!) CSS if you're still stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using CSS you can set the margin using the `:last-child` property

```
<style>
    div a img{margin-left:10px;}
    div a:last-child img{margin-left:50px;}
</style>
<div>
    <a href="#" class="noHover" title=""><img src="http://www.iwebsource.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/css3.png" /></a>
    <a href="#" class="noHover" title=""><img src="http://www.iwebsource.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/css3.png" /></a>
    <a href="#" class="noHover" title=""><img src="http://www.iwebsource.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/css3.png" /></a>
</div>
```

[FIDDLE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hqdt5/)

Comment: Ah, thanks, I wrote it like: .latestWork img:last-child {
 margin-right: 0%;
} but apparently that was wrong. This works!